# Check if the administrator has logged into WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a complicated weird system where we need to check if the wordpress administrator has logged in and by logged in i dont just mean the session but initial second when the query is sent to validate the credentials entered. I was thinking doing traditional php where I do something like the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) { // do something }
```

But that would be the incorrect way. Where exactly would i look to see this peice , i believe its wp-login.php but wasnt able to find what i was looking for.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
global $current_user;
$user = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

$userRole = (!empty($user->roles) ? $user->roles : '');
if(in_array('administrator', $userRole)) {
     // do your stuff
}
```

or you can try :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Answer (score 0):

We can add some custom action inside the filter hook [**`login_redirect`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-login.php#L782). If the form was not submitted, the `$user` param is a WP_Error Object.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user )
{
    if( !is_wp_error( $user ) && in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
    {
        # Do your thing; here just inspecting the WP_User Object
        wp_die( 
            sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $user, true ) ),
            'Var dump',
            array( 
                'response' => 500, 
                'back_link' => true 
            )
        );
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use very neat Wordpress function to determine the user capabilities, it is called `current_user_can()`:

`<?php 
if ( current_user_can('update_core') ) {
 echo 'The current user is Administrator or Super administrator (in Multisite)';
}`

Only **Administrators** of single site installations have the below list of capabilities. In Multi-site, only the **Super Admin** has these abilities:

```
update_core 
update_plugins 
update_themes 
install_plugins 
install_themes 
delete_themes 
edit_plugins 
edit_themes 
edit_users 
create_users 
delete_users 
unfiltered_html
```

See here for more [information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).